# How do I set auto height on this CSS?

Tags: css, height

I have the following CSS:

```
#content div.container {
  float: left;
  margin: 40px 0px 0px 0px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 320px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ffffff;
}
```

How do I ensure that the height of the container will re-arrange according to the content in there if it goes longer than 320px?

I tried using: height 100% auto;  and I tried removing the float property but the height doesn't readjust.  I am a bit new to this so not sure what to fix.

Comment: Add max-height perhaps?

Comment: The code you've posted will do what you're asking.  The div will get larger to accommodate more content; you haven't done anything to prevent that.  Is there something in #content's styles that stops it from growing?

Comment: add min-height or max-height to you container. also your min-height is overwritten by height:100%

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with your code, you just have to use `min-height` and `height: auto;`

CSS

```
#content div.container {
  float: left;
  margin: 40px 0px 0px 0px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 320px;
  height: auto;
  background: #ffffff;
}
```

**[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/vinizinmoraes/DuNCr/)**

Comment: I think i have other elements that are causing an issue.  Let me take a second look at my code.  Thanks!

Comment: @starbucks If you get any trouble just ask and i will see if I can help you out

Answer (score 0):

try

```
padding: 5px;
```

or however much padding you want

if that doesn't work, try also adding

```
overflow: auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

There nothing wrong with your code
try this jfiddle [http://fiddle.jshell.net](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Qq7VB/)